# Cgo can't find standard libraries like <iostream>

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I'm trying to include C++ code in my Go code, but  isn't recognized.

I first thought that it considers it as C code and try (and fail) to compile as such, but removing the include line actually gives me c++ error troubleshooting like this
`error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’`
The code compiles correctly with g++.

I have tried to add the -lstdc++ LDLFLAG, and add the path to the lib in CXXFLAG but it doesn't change a thing.

I have made some other tests (and all fail) but this is the smallest one.

This is the c++ files

```cpp
test.cpp

#include "test.hpp"
    int test() 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, World! ";
        return 0;
    }

test.hpp 
#include <iostream>
int test() ;
```

And this is my go file

```golang
//#cgo CXXFLAGS: -I/usr/lib/
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib/ -lstdc++
//#include "test.hpp"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.test()
}
```

I compile using `go build` but I have also tried to use `env CGO_ENABLED CGO_CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" go build` (the env part is fish specific) and it returns the same error.

It's supposed to compile correctly, but instead I have `iostream: No such file or directory`.

**EDIT :**
I tried to add `CFLAGS: -x c++` as suggested in the comments, the compiler searches at the right place, but I get another error `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘_cgo_96e70225d9dd_Cfunc_test(void*)::<unnamed struct>*’ [-fpermissive]` and I don't know if it's related to this new flafg

Comment: I don't see evidence that it's "trying to compile it as C code", only that it cannot find one of the standard library headers.

Comment: This isn't the only code I've tried to compile and it doesn't understand c++ syntax, I'll edit my question

Comment: You should also show how you trigger this process, i.e. what commands you use.

Comment: Actually you were right, it doesn't have anything to do with C code, I corrected the question, thank you very much

Comment: Use `#cgo CFLAGS: -x c++` and `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++`

Comment: Try adding `--verbose` to `CXXFLAGS` (or whatever fits your compiler) and then pass the `-x` command-line option to `go build` (or `go install`—whatever you're using). Then see what the C++ compiler writes out about how it processed its input files. (Well, and a silly but obligatory question: is that C++ code compilable "as is"? I mean directly, not via the `go` toolchain.)

Comment: On a side note: if you intend to call functions of your C++ code from Go, you have to put their declarations in the `extern "C" { ... }` blocks to inhibit [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) which will make the exported functions unavailable for linking with the Go code. (More info [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage)).

Comment: @georgeok thanks, I tried that, and it's correctly calling cc1plus and not cc1 but I have another error now, it's in my edited answer

Comment: @kostix thank you, it's a bit clearer now with the -v option
And yes, it is compilable "as is", I said that it compiles correctly with g++.

Comment: So, what's the exact error now? That one about invalid cast or about missing `<iostream>`? If it's the former, have you applied proper external linkage rule to your function as suggested in my first comment?

Comment: Right now, the <iostream> issue is resolved, but I'm not sure if the invalid cast is related to the solution given or not.
And yes I have applied the extern "C" around the declaration, but it doesn't change a thing to the invalid cast error

Comment: iostream issue was resolved with `-x c++` but I was facing the error `_cgo_export.c:27:33: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'struct (anonymous struct at _cgo_export.c:24:2) *'.  Then I used a .h file and wrapped the C++ functions with `extern "C"` and implemented the methods in a `cpp` file, then compiled it into `.so` file, and included in go program, then it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cgo makes it very easy to wrap C with Go, but C++ is a bit different. You have to `extern "C"` the functions that you want to [make a function-name in C++ have 'C' linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/1199408), otherwise the linker won't see the function. So, the actual problem is in the C++ header file. If you can't change the C++ code because it's a library, you may have to write wrappers ([example](https://github.com/draffensperger/go-interlang/tree/master/go_to_cxx/c_wrapper)).

This will compile:

```
.
├── test.cpp
├── test.go
└── test.hpp
```

**test.hpp**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int test();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
int test() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World! ";
    return 0;
}
```

**test.go**

```
package main

// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -I/usr/lib/
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib/ -lstdc++
// #include "test.hpp"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.test()
}
```

Put the files in the same folder, 
run `go build`

> Hello, World!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it finally works. However, why would you put `#include <iostream>` in the .cpp and not the .hpp?

Comment: I believe in C++ most people put the includes that are required in the headers and whatever is only required in the cpp files there

Comment: I see now, but why does it give me the same error as before (`iostream: No such file or directory`) when I put it back in the hpp? (even if I put it inside the extern "C")

Comment: tbh I am not sure about that. Probably it's because we import it in the test.go file and that only expect C-like code

Comment: So say I have c++ specific code in the hpp, I won't be able to make it work, right? Because that was my issue from the get-go

Comment: I think so. That's probably why people end up writing wrappers.